# Python - How to sort through my list

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, reverse

Basically all I'm trying to do is get the list to sort and display in different ways. But it seems after I do the first print it will get "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable". I'm assuming that's because I'm at the end of the list and need to restart at the beginning? Not sure how to do that or if that's the reason.

```
    ##vars

Index = 0
NumSize = 0
NumInput = 0
ManNum = 0

##Asking for list size

NumSize = int(input("How many numbers would you like to enter?:\n====>"))

##Declaring list

Numbers = [0] * NumSize

##Collecting data

for Index in range(NumSize):
    NumInput = int(input("Please enter a number:\n====>"))
    Numbers[Index] = NumInput

##Getting highest number

MaxNum = max(Numbers)

##Printing list

print("::::The numbers you entered were::::")
for Numbers in Numbers:
    print(Numbers)

##Sorting list small to large

Numbers.sort()
print("::::The numbers while sorted::::")
for Numbers in Numbers:
    print(Numbers)

##Sorting list large to small

Numbers.reverse()
print("::::The numbers reversed::::")
for Numbers in Numbers:
    print(Numbers)

##Printing largest number

print("::::Largest number::::\n",
       MaxNum)
```

Comment: Your code looks like java, stick to PEP8, seriously.

Answer (score 5):

You use

```
for Numbers in Numbers:
    print(Numbers)
```

You should not name your iterating variable the same name as your collection

try this

```
for number in Numbers:
    print(number)
```

Answer (score 2):

do not call the iterator with the same name as the collection, as you overwrite the later

```
for Numbers in Numbers:
```

this destroys "Numbers" array and after the loop "Numbers" is the last element of "Numbers" instead. Change all loops to

```
for number in Numbers:
```

Answer (score 0):

Use anything instead of `Numbers` in your `for` loop,
so that

```
for i in Numbers:`
    dosomething
```

If you print Numbers then you will see that it just carry last number you inserted in the list.

```
print Numbers
>>> #last Number of List
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a different variable than `Numbers` in your loops. You can also use `sorted(Numbers)` and `reversed(Numbers)` to reduce the amount of variable assignments you have to do. If you don't plan to reuse `MaxNum`, you can do that directly in the `print` as well.

Here is the fully updated program:

```
##vars
Index = 0
NumSize = 0
NumInput = 0

##Asking for list size
NumSize = int(input("How many numbers would you like to enter?:\n====>"))

##Declaring list
Numbers = [0] * NumSize

##Collecting data
for Index in range(NumSize):
    NumInput = int(input("Please enter a number:\n====>"))
    Numbers[Index] = NumInput

##Printing list
print("::::The numbers you entered were::::")
for number in Numbers:
    print(number)

##Sorting list small to large
print("::::The numbers while sorted::::")
for number in sorted(Numbers):
    print(number)

##Sorting list large to small
print("::::The numbers reversed::::")
for number in reversed(Numbers):
    print(number)

##Printing largest number
print("::::Largest number::::")
print max(Numbers)
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer is already given above. But for the explanation purpose here is what is going wrong.

```
>>> Numbers = [1, 4 , 10, 8]    #This is creating a list.
>>> for Numbers in Numbers:     #Now when you are iterating it definately gives the result
...     print(Numbers)
... 
1
4
10
8
>>> Numbers                     #But now check what is in Numbers
8
>>>
```

You didn't wanted the above.

Note: >>> is the python interpretor prompt

As mentioned in the comment, please start writing code in pythonic way.
Which is:

1. You do not need to initialize variables like you did. You just need to assign them before  you use them.
2. When you ask for the inputs. you do need to go do `list[index]` instead you could use `append` method.